# Spring mvc - Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

[image]My dispatcher servlet xml is named as cnc-dispatcher-servlet-xml. But why its pointing to WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml? I have the config xml file under WEB-INF. Due to this I'm not able to call the controller. It throws me the following error

### cnccontroller

```
package com.cnc.cnccontroller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;   
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class CncController {
String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("in controller");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    mv.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Welcome to first page");
    return mv;
}
}
```

### cnc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cnc.cnccontroller.CncController" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
```

My web.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<display-name>CNC</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/cnc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Change servlet name to `<servlet-name>cnc-dispatcher</servlet-name>`..if error goes let me know i will post as answer

Comment: Please add your pom.xml. Maybe the root case is in servlet version inconsistency.

Comment: Show your controller

Comment: @Sam, i have changed the servlet name as cnc-servlet.. now its showing the 404 status error.. i have updated with controller

Comment: @Syed the check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing comments to answer..

> 1.Your servlet name should be `cnc-dispatcher` because your file name is `cnc-dispathcer-servlet.xml.`,whatever you mention before `-servlet` you should mention as servlet name.
>
> 2.Since you are mentioning `new ModelAndView("helloworld");` and in your dispatcher-servlet `prefix` and `suffix` are just `/WEB-INF/` and `.jsp`, make sure you have helloworld.jsp under `/WEB-INF` and not under any other sub folder(if yes update the prefix)

**Update 1:** Add mvc annotation driven to dispatcher servlet.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="package to scan" /> 
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

**Update 2**: And in jsp change `{welcomeMessage}` to `${welcomeMessage}`.

Comment: everthing I have kept in th correct manner. still it throws the same 404

Comment: Show your directory structure and check the browser console for detailed error(inspect element and in console click on 404 link)

Comment: It just says .. HTTP Status 404 -.. There is no link attached to it

Comment: @syed in the browser console too?? show your directory structure

Comment: http://localhost:8080/CNC/hello?name=Eric --.> this is not available.. can u see the context configuration location

Comment: @Syed you have the request handler for hello so no need to worry...it's something else..show directory structure or helloworld jsp

Comment: added directory structure.. plz check it

Comment: Your configuration is correct.. I think exception will be displayed on browser console(after doing inspect element)..And make sure that your request is hitting to controller (by placing a breakpoint)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124381/discussion-between-syed-and-sam).

Comment: it gives WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CNC/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cnc-dispatcher'
 when I start the server itself

Comment: Add Mvc annotation-driven tag in dispactcher servlet

Comment: plz send me the snippet

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven /> add this in dispatcher servlet

Comment: Got it..Thanks.. Mistake was I was pointing directly to controller.. it should be mapped to package

Answer (score 0):

Change your servlet name to cnc-dispatcher like below.
Your dispatcher servlet xml is looked upon by your `<servlet-name>`.

Also in your `contextConfigLocation` should look up for your context xml or spring config xml where you define you spring beans to be loaded and initialized.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<display-name>CNC</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cnc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cnc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/<your application context/config xml></param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks.. But now it is throwing the other error.. HTTP Status 404 http://localhost:8080/CNC/hello?name=Eric.. I will update my cnc-dispatcher-servlet.xml too

Comment: show your error stack trace.. it shows your servlet was not initialized successful and failed at server start up

Comment: after that its not showing any error in console.. just 404 error.. will updsate the controller too

Comment: As mentioned your contextConfigLocation is wrong it should point to your application context xml which defined spring beans not your cnc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. look at my posted web.xml in answer

Comment: I didnt get about application context xml.. do u have any references for it to see how to use it